# Inconveniente en la instalación del Virtualenv dentro de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.7

Cordial saludo quiero pedirles un favor acerca de como instalar el componente virtual env de Python en mi computador

He instalado Python y Django en mi computador de acuerdo a los siguientes pasos:

1. pip install virtualenv
2. cree una carpeta que se llama introduccion
   ya dentro de esa carpeta, realizo el siguiente proceso:
3. pip -V
4. pongo dentro de la carpeta que he creado lo siguiente:

virtual env

y me aparece lo siguiente:

"virtual" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Vale mencionar que he instalado Python 3.11.4 y Django -4.2.3

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: es virtual o virtualenv, todo junto?

Comment: Es en ambiente virtual

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un entorno virtual se debe ejecutar `python -m venv <nombre_entorno>`, y después se tiene que activar el entorno si se está en windows con `source <nombre_entorno>/Scripts/activate`.